# Multiple Select ignores width !important CSS in sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where a multiple select is somehow getting it's width via javascript dynamically but I can't seem to find where.  I have nothing in my CSS that specifies a width of 411 px.

[Website of Problem here](http://bit.ly/1CdA7ls)

The width of the sidebar is the same always so I tried the following CSS and it is ignored?  Am I missing some syntax?  I've tried both of these and they do not work:

```
#widget-wrap .chosen-container-multi {width:200px !important;}
```

and

```
.widget-wrap .chosen-container-multi {width:200px !important;}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please share a link, because it's difficult to tell what's wrong just looking to image

Comment: Doh!  Brainfart...sorry about that thanks.  Updated with website link now @Morpheus

Comment: please check if, is there any inline style in your code setting width? remove it.

Comment: @Ashutosh Nigam It has inline style, but `!important` should override. I have added `.widget-wrap .chosen-container-multi {width:200px !important;}` and it works. What browser are you using?

Comment: please check where u define the css properties because there arent given in the webpage. Cause if I add this the div will get 200px of width.

Comment: Try change your css ul > li > .chosen-container-multi {width:200px !important;}

Comment: I am using chrome.  try setting it for div.chosen-containing.chosen-container-multi  ... the exact address that is appearing in blue color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some inline styles declared in the widget template itself, rather than generated with JS.

Ideally you should remove the inline style from the template; otherwise this CSS will work just fine:

```
.chosen-container {
  width:123px !important;
}
```

I can't see why your existing CSS wouldn't work other than it simply not being uploaded.

Comment: The inline style is added by `chosen` javascript plugin, but I agree that it should work.

Answer (score 2):

the control misbehaving is ul.chosen-choice so please set css as follows:

```
 ul.chosen-choice {width:200px !important;}
```